# How to prevent starting/running service until ansible tasks get finish for all user?

Tags: linux, centos, ansible

I want to prevent running/starting service/command (like /usr/local/script/xyz or supervisorctl stop xyz) until all ansible tasks get finished on all machines.

If xys service/command running, then I want to stop and apply lock before running ansible tasks & once those ansible tasks get over, then I want to release lock from that service/command.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your question is a little vague.  You may need to provide more information about what your are trying to accomplish.  Please check the FAQ for information on how to write questions.

Answer (score 0):

By default, plays run with a [linear strategy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html), in which all hosts will run each task before any host starts the next task. Start the service in the last task of a playbook.